# C++ allocator<X>::deallocate(NULL,1) allowed?

Tags: c++, memory-management, null, free, allocator

Both `free(NULL)` and `::operator delete(NULL)` are allowed.  Does the allocator concept (e.g. std::allocator also allow `deallocate(NULL,1)`, or is it required to put your own guard around it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to add your own check.

According to §20.4.​1.1/8, `deallocate` requires:

> p shall be a pointer value obtained from allocate(). n shall equal the value passed as the
>   first argument to the invocation of allocate which returned p.

`allocate` throws an exception when storage can't be given (§20.4.​1.1/7). In other words, `allocate` never returns 0, and therefore `deallocate` should never get a 0. Passing a 0 would lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.