# Allocating zero objects with std::allocator::allocate(0) in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, language-lawyer, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocator

`new int[0]` is permitted in C++ but is `std::allocator<int>().allocate(0)` well defined?
More general, must all Allocators accept `0` as a parameter to allocate?

Edit:
After reading the answers I tested Visual Studio's `std::allocator`: `allocate(0)` gives `nullptr`

`deallocate(nullptr, anything)` is a nop.

So using `nullptr` is a good suggestion, but the standard do not demand that `deallocate(nullptr, 0)` is a nop, see [C++ allocator::deallocate(NULL,1) allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104543/c-allocatorxdeallocatenull-1-allowed)

Answer (score 4):

> Table 34 — Cpp17Allocator requirements
>   Memory is allocated for n objects of type T but objects are not constructed. allocate may
>   throw an appropriate exception.174 [Note: If n == 0, the return value is unspecified. —end note]

I would read that as "The allocator shall/should handle `n == 0`, not throw and return a value that might be a valid pointer or be `nullptr`."

Comment: I suspect that's related to the implementation of (if not directly inherited from) C's [**7.22.3 Memory management functions**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3):  "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object."

Comment: @AndrewHenle [yes but it is not allowed to return nullptr like C is](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1024212665554558976)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed `new int[0]` is well-defined. Note that you are required to call `delete[]` on the returned pointer, and the behavior on dereferencing the pointer is undefined.

Similar rules apply to `std::allocator().allocate(0)`: you can't dereference the returned pointer, and you need to clean up memory in the normal way by calling `std::allocator::deallocate`.

An allocator is allowed to throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception; you could deal with the 0 parameter case by doing that, without contravening any requirements laid down by the standard. Returning `nullptr` is an alternative.